# Is it possible to filter choices on a foreign key in Django Admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Here is my situation:
I have three models : Grade, Course and Program.
Grade has a foreign key to Course and Course has a foreign key to Program.

Here is my problem:
When I need to add some grades in my admin panel, I have a listbox full of Course. First problem : same course name can be found in two different program and it is difficult to identify in the listbox. For now it is shown as Program.name - Course.name

I was wondering if there was any solution that can help me to filter my course list by program when I want to create  or modify a grade. (I'm talking about the grade creation interface, not the list before that interface).

EDIT:
Thanks for your answers. I think I'll have to code my own widget make my filter client-side with AJAX.

Comment: Are you talking about client-side filtering, i.e. select a program, and the course list changes to reflect only courses in that program? Or, do you just want to filter the course list by a specific program at run-time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write such a filter with AJAX (using jQuery or a similar framework would be the easiest way to do so). You'd create a custom form widget with two lists. The first would be populated with all available programs by the server when the page is loaded. Your javascript would then wait for a selection to be made, and then ask the server (thats the AJAX part) for a list of the courses in that program, and update the second list accordingly.

However, for your situation I would say that is overkill; it would be far easier to do as [jammon's answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103132/is-it-possible-to-filter-choices-on-a-foreign-key-in-django-admin-panel/6105717#6105717) and put the admin for the Grade model within the corresponding Course admin (this is known as an inlined model admin; see [the Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) on the subject). Unfortunately the example code given in their answer doesn't work, so I've created the following example which works for me.

The basic way of configuring the Django admin is to simply register your models with the admin site in `admin.py`. You're probably doing something along the following lines:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Program, Course, Grade

admin.site.register(Program)
admin.site.register(Course)
admin.site.register(Grade)
```

Instead, we want to edit the grades for a course *within* the admin section of the course itself. First, we need to define an inline administration class for the grade:

```
class GradeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Grade
    extra = 1
```

Note you can choose to inherit from either `admin.TabularInline` or `admin.StackedInline`. Normally, I prefer the look of the `TabularInline` but it can depend on your model so try both. The `extra` option defines how many blank forms will be shown to the user.

Next we need to tell the Course admin page to add the inline forms:

```
class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Course
    inlines = (GradeInline,)
```

Finally, we no longer want to show the independent grade admin, so we don't need to register it with the admin site. Instead, we must specify that our custom admin class be used for the Course model. This means the final `admin.py` file for the application is as follows:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Program, Course, Grade

class GradeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Grade
    extra = 1

class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Course
    inlines = (GradeInline,)

admin.site.register(Program)
admin.site.register(Course, CourseAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, here is the solution I came to:

Define a InlineModelAdmin for Grade in the ModelAdmin of Course.

```
class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class GradeInline(admin.StackedInline):
        model = Grade
        fk_name = 'course'
        extra = 2
        and so on
```

Then you can add and edit the grades in the the change_view of the course they belong to and you don't have to select the course at all.

And for telling the courses of different programs apart in the listings I'd redefine `course.__unicode__` to return something like 'grade.name (program.name)'.